# Logback-classic in Jboss and Spring

Tags: java, spring, maven, jboss, logback

I'm working on a project where I thought I would try using logback-classic for debugging and log rotation. I'm using this in a Maven context for building and creating a .war file to be deployed in JBoss 7.1 Application Server.

I've placed a logback.xml file in the resources folder in the code and a logback-test.xml in test/resources.

The active jar I'm using is the SLF4J to print the actual debugging.

```
public class MyClass extends MultiActionController {
  private Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyClass.class);

  public MyClass() {
    logger.debug("hello");
  }
}
```

When I run a JUnit test on the code in Maven itself it works, but after building a .war file i don't get any debugging in STDOUT nor can I find a file created.

I know that I've removed the actual logging from STDOUT in the config file, but where is the logging going...

the logback.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">

        <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.ThresholdFilter">
            <level>DEBUG</level>
        </filter>

        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <FileNamePattern>logs/myproject.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log</FileNamePattern>
            <MaxHistory>30</MaxHistory>
        </rollingPolicy> 

        <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder">
            <pattern>%d{yyMMdd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%-5.5level] [%-25.25logger] %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <root level="debug">
        <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
    </root>
</configuration>
```

The folder "logs" do I need to explicit create it in the JBoss instance or need to refer relative to it for this to work? Or is there something I missed? Do I need to put the logback.xml file in the JBoss instance?

best,
Henrik

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly you should ensure that the `logback.xml` is at the classpath, e.g. `WEB-INF/classes/logback.xml` as the mentioning at [Chapter 3: Logback configuration](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/configuration.html).

The [Chapter 4: Appenders](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/appenders.html) mentions about *FileAppender* and *RollingFileAppender* properties as

> **file** **String** The name of the file to write to. If the file does not exist, it is created. On the MS Windows platform users frequently forget to escape back slashes. For example, the value c:\temp\test.log is not likely to be interpreted properly as '\t' is an escape sequence interpreted as a single tab character (\u0009). Correct values can be specified as c:/temp/test.log or alternatively as c:\temp\test.log. The File option has no default value.
>   If the parent directory of the file does not exist, FileAppender will automatically create it, including any necessary but nonexistent parent directories.

The example is for logback.xml is as the following:-

```
<configuration>
  <appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <file>logFile.log</file>
    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
      <!-- daily rollover -->
      <fileNamePattern>logFile.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log</fileNamePattern>

      <!-- keep 30 days' worth of history -->
      <maxHistory>30</maxHistory>
    </rollingPolicy>

    <encoder>
      <pattern>%-4relative [%thread] %-5level %logger{35} - %msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
  </appender> 

  <root level="DEBUG">
    <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
  </root>
</configuration>
```

I hope this may help.

Comment: Hmm.... it might be that the file ends up outside of the /classes folder in the WEB-INF, I need to check that.

Regarding the escaping, I'm not using windows at all, OSX and Linux Server in the end.

Comment: The file seems to be in the WEB-INF/classes/ folder in the .war file...

the path to the log-file, does it need to exist or does it need to be created? I.E the folders?

Comment: The tag `<file>...</file>` is required. I would suggest the create the dedicate directory for storing the log file, e.g. `/home/myapp/logs`. Then the configure should be `<file>/home/myapp/logs/logFile.log</file>`. **edited**: the path permission should allow the JBoss to write the log file as well.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define the file-tag (as the previous answers already said). But you also need to know how it's interpreted. Logback sees it as relative to the application it's used in. So if you only use

```
<file>logs/<myfile>.log</file>
```

logback **should** create a "logs"-folder in the root of your JBoss (more specific: the folder where the .sh-script you start it with is located). Check from the root of your JBoss to see if you can find your logs-folder and file from there.

Comment: I see, so, I might have a logs folder in my bin structure then I suppose. I'll check it out.